# On Cygwin, how do I install curl from hackage?

Tags: haskell, cygwin, libcurl, ghc, hackage

From a Windows command prompt,

```
c:\>cabal install curl
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring curl-1.3.5...
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
curl-1.3.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
sh: runGenProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

I have installed Cygwin's curl-devel package, but from a Cygwin prompt `cabal install curl` also fails, even if I point `--extra-lib-dirs` and `--extra-include-dirs` at it, *e.g.*,

```
$ cabal install curl --extra-include-dirs=c:/cygwin/usr/include \
                     --extra-lib-dirs=c:/cygwin/usr/lib
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring curl-1.3.5...
[...]
configure: error: curl libraries not found, so curl package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
curl-1.3.5 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
exit: ExitFailure 1
```

The above attempts are with ghc-6.10.3, Cabal-1.6.0.3, and cabal-install-0.6.2.

Comment: Just use cygwin's setup.exe to install packages - or use cyg-apt (http://code.google.com/p/cyg-apt/) to do it. - Lastly if the package isn't in cygwin's package list, get the source and configure/make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Installing curl from hackage on Cygwin](http://gbacon.blogspot.com/2009/06/installing-curl-from-hackage-on-cygwin.html).

Comment: This did not work for me when I tried.  I still get the error mentioned in this article.  Any luck doing this on Windows 7 with the latest haskell platform?